# How to make deep links to the iOS app work on Twiiter?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

On the iOS app side I've implemented custom URL scheme, and on the web I've added metatags for Facebook(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/metadata-reference/) and Twitter (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/app-card).
When link is shared on the Facebook everything works fine (iOS app opens correctly). Unfortunately when link is shared on the Twitter website opens instead of the mobile app.
Do you have any idea how I can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You cant, Twitter doesn't allow universal or deepLinking out of their app.

twitter captcha all link presses in their app and handle how it is loaded.

They don't want to have users leave their app, so they don't handle links in that way.

https://blog.branch.io/what-the-twitter-update-means-for-deep-linking/